# AWS lambda python multiple files application can't import one from another

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I have the following structure of my AWS lambda project:

```
module
  app.py
  b.py
```

`app.py` is my default aws lambda function with `lambda_handler`, it works fine. I decided to pull all the heavy calculations out of it to function `calc` of `b.py`.

Then, I imported it to `app.py`:

```
from module.b import calc
```

Now, when I run it locally with `sam local invoke Function --event events/event.json`, it raises an error:

> {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'module'"}

It seems to me that when it prepares the code to run, it moves the files to some other directory, so the imports break. To fix this, I tried to use relative import:

```
from .b import calc
```

But it also raised an error:

> {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Unable to import module 'app': attempted relative import with no known parent package"}

How do I setup a multi-file python application on aws lambda?

Comment: please take a screenshot of your root lambda folder and another where is b.py please...

Comment: this gist is useful: https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/06a64ba80cf3fe886053f0ca6d375bc0

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is how me resolve that problem.

First your root folder need to seem like this:

```
lambda_folder
    lambda_function.py // Or your main.py.... this file have the method lambda_handler
```

Now... When I use multiple files... I always use a lib folder. Like this:

```
lambda_folder
    lib
        lib1.py
        lib2.py
        lib3.py
    lambda_function.py
```

**IMPORTANT**

Inside your lib folder you always need an `__init__.py` or you can't see the files inside.

```
lambda_folder
    lib
        lib1.py
        lib2.py
        lib3.py
        __init__.py
    lambda_function.py
```

**NOTE:** the `__init__.py` needs to have the two underscores before and after `init`.

**EXAMPLE**

**lib1.py**

```
def sum(a,b):
    return a+b
```

**lambda_function.py**

```
from lib import lib1
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    result = lib.sum(5,4)

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": "hi " + result
    }
```

And that's all.

Comment: Thanks! This actually helped.

Comment: this does not work!

Comment: There is a minor mistake.   <result = lib.sum(5,4)> should be <result = lib1.sum(5,4)> . Not 'lib' it is 'lib1', the file_name of function, not the 'folder_name'.  Kind of obvious though. Then it will work.

Answer (score -1):

Use
`__init__.py` Inside of your module and import you Inside file Packages Inside of it like `import app.py`